# CyanogenMod 11 installer for Xperia SP

Tags: installation, cyanogenmod

I downloaded the CyanogenMod installer from the Google PlayStore however on installation it says my device is not supported and if i should wish to continue, it will be at my own risk. Is there any harm if I should choose to proceed with the installation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device is officially supported by Cyanogen, you can at 99,9% run the installer without any issues. But if you would like to go the "secure" way, I recommend the manual method.